# Finite Difference Problem

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Any help with the following question would be appreciated.

Consider:

$u_{xx}+u_{yy}=0$

in $0<x<1,\ 0<y<1$

with $u=0$ when $x=0,\ x=1,\ y=1$ and

$$u=256x^2(1-x)\ \mathrm{when}\ y=0$$

calculate an approximation to the solution of this problem using finite differences with the coarse grid $\Delta x=\Delta y = 1/4$

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Any method of approximation has been suggested in your course? Because, I mean, I can give you an approximation that will be very bad, but if your teacher has something in mind perhaps the solution will be more interesting to look at.

Comment: In class no exact approximation was mentioned though I believe Jacobi Iteration, I just don't know exactly how to use it.

Comment: Jacobi iteration is a numerical method which uses some process to determine a numerical solution. In other words, you have some matrix $U_{ij}$ where the coefficient of $U_{ij}$ is $u(0 + (i-1)\Delta x, 0 + (j-1) \Delta y)$, where $1 \le i,j \le 5$ to cover your whole grid. I only deduced this from reading the Wikipedia pages ; perhaps you should read your notes and understand this method better, this would be a good place to start. If you were coming on MSE hoping that someone would give you an example on how to use it then I leave it to someone else to do that, but you are at the good place.